# How can I move several columns from one table to a new one to-many table?

Tags: sqlite, refactoring

I'd like to refactor my database by splitting a single table into two.  I'd like to moving a few existing columns to a new table.  For instance, suppose I want to move the `home_address` and `work_address` fields in the below `Employee` table to a new `Address` table.

How can I accomplish this **using sqlite**?

**Before:**

```
Employee Table
   employee_id (Primary)
   name
   home_address
   home_city
   work_address
   work_city
```

**After:**

```
Employee Table
   employee_id (Primary)
   name
   home_address_id
   work_address_id

Address Table
   address_id (Primary)
   address
   city
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd propose a bit different refactoring : `(Employee : employee_id, name), AddressType (address_type_id, name), Address :the same as yours, Employee_Address(address_id, address_type_id,employee_id)` .

Comment: @a1ex07 Do you mean because that way you could add indefinite types of addresses without further schema modifications?

Comment: Exactly. I'd go even further, and get rid of `Employee`, replacing it with `Party`, `PartyRole` (one of roles will be employee).

Comment: One of my concerns about using your idea, which from a pure programming point of view seems better since it's more general, is that I'm actually implementing this using [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/).  I'm not sure OrmLite supports that type of join query.  If it does, that would be a good follow-up refactoring question.

Comment: I've been involved in a pretty much the same refactoring for last couple of months... The only difference is RDMS; I'm using Oracle. I can tell for sure that from programming perspective it can be solved, but it does require some efforts (especially in the beginning) . I'm not very familiar with SQLite, even though I had some experience with it; I can say it's quite well designed database for some tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer migrations to be simple and straightforward, without extra logic, etc. At least when you run them only once or so.

So, first check what is max(employee_id), below assumes that it less than 10000 (and it is integer).

```
create table employee_new(employee_id,name,home_address_id,work_address_id);
insert into employee_new select employee_id,name,employee_id,employee_id+10000 from employee;
create table address(address_id,address,city);
insert into address select employee_id,home_address,home_city from employee; 
insert into address select employee_id+10000,work_address,work_city from employee; 
alter table employee rename to employee_old;
alter table employee_new rename to employee;
```